# Adding a new NOT NULL field to a table causes an error

Tags: 8, database

When attempting to add a new column to a table within an update hook, the error `Null value not allowed: 1138 Invalid use of NULL value` occurred, the definition was changed to allow NULL, and the value for existing rows was set to NULL.

```
function MYMODULE_update_8101() {
  Drupal::database()->schema()->addField(
    'MYMODULE_table',
    'created',
    [
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ]
  );
}
```

When adding the column to the database with an SQL query, using the `NOT NULL` restriction causes the field to have a default value of 0, and no error happens.

How can the error be fixed, and the proper schema set?

Comment: have you tried `'null' => FALSE,` by removing `'not null' => TRUE,`

Comment: Having the `'not null'` restriction is a valuable and required attribute of the column and simply removing it does not actually fix the problem, it just masks the error.  There's a similar reason for not providing a `'default'` attribute.  Using `'initial'` is the correct approach, but unfortunately not very discoverable from searching based on the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field spec sets `'not null' => TRUE` but does not define a default value, the column is created allowing null values and later altered to disallow them (see the mysql driver [Schema::addField()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Driver!mysql!Schema.php/function/Schema%3A%3AaddField/8), and the `$fixnull` variable).  The second query attempting add the restriction fails, causing the error.

To fix the error, either

- An `'initial'` value needs to be added to the spec provided to `addField()`

  ```
  Drupal::database()->schema()->addField(
    'MYMODULE_table',
    'created',        
    [
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'initial' => 0,
    ]
  )
  ```
- Or a `'default'` value needs to be added to the spec provided to `addField()`.
  When providing a default value, the spec in `hook_schema()` should also be changed to match.

Comment: I think what I suggested it is worked :)